# I can not get config variable value in a function as a parameter

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, laravel-4, parameter-passing

My problem is that I want to call a function value as a parameter of another function from config of my Laravel system as follows:

```
 public function functionName($parameterName = Config::get('app.varName'))
 {
    ...
 }
```

I know it seems crazy but I need to call a value from config in many functions as a default parameter. But naturally like above, it returns syntax error. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the shorthand if:

```
public function functionName($parameterName = null)
{
    $parameterName = $parameterName ?: Config::get('app.varName');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this;

```
public function functionName($parameterName = null)
{
    if($parameterName === null) { 
        $parameterName = Config::get('app.varName');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes now I am using it like you said. I am looking for another shorter option if exists.